# RegEx para validar numeros de movil españoles

Tags: java, string, regex

¿Cómo creo una expresión regular que me valide números de teléfono móvil español?

Deben seguir las siguientes normas.

Al inicio:

- [opcional] `+34`
- [opcional] `34`
- [opcional] `0034`

A partir de aquí debe tener:

- Exactamente 9 números (los espacios y guiones están permitidos)
- El primer número debe ser `6` o `7`

Válidos:

```
666444555
666-444-555
666 44 45 55
666-44-45-55
+34666555444
0034666555444
```

No válidos

```
935554488
+44777555444
800444666
635*554*488
635/554/488
```

> **NOTA:** Está etiquetado [java](/questions/tagged/java) porque es como voy a parsear el `String` y por si queréis mostrar código. Eso sí, no es estrictamente necesario, con la expresión regular tengo bastante.

Comment: jaja que cosas claro en esta pregunta lo dejas claro, pero yo solo vi la otra pregunta

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Esta expresión regular debería servirte:

```
(\+34|0034|34)?[ -]*(6|7)[ -]*([0-9][ -]*){8}
```

No tengo un entorno Java a mano, pero todos los casos de prueba mencionados pasan en la herramienta de [RegexPlanet](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html).

Comment: @JordiCastilla el número 6-66444555 es válido? esa expresión regular permite poner '-' en casi cualquier parte del número.

Comment: @Robertiano La pregunta sólo dice "los espacios y guiones están permitidos", así que interpreto que los grupos de dígitos pueden ser de cualquier longitud.

Comment: Ya @Konamiman, pero al ver los ejemplos, he pensado que quizás la pregunta descripción no era exacta. Tendría que haber puesto el comentario a su pregunta, no a tu respuesta. Si la solución se tiene que ajustar a los ejemplos, la expresión regular queda un poco montruo `(\+34|0034|34)?[ -]*(6|7)([0-9]){2}[ -]?(([0-9]){2}[ -]?([0-9]){2}[ -]?([0-9]){2}|([0-9]){3}[ -]?([0-9]){3})`

Comment: @Robertiano si, aunque no clarifique para nosotros, poner un guion o un espacio se considera valido porque se ignora posteriormente y solo sirve para la visibilidad, cada cual que elija el formato en el que lo vea mejor :)

Comment: funciona perfecta, lo único que hay que tener en cuenta (para `Java`) es escapar la barra invertida ``\`` del principio.

Answer (score 5):

Yo te recomiendo usar `libphonenumber` (la [librería de Google](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber) para validar números telefónicos). Tiene muchas ventajas comparado con hacer tu propia implementación, por ejemplo que no tienes que mantenerlo tú y que te da el número en formato internacional, no importando cómo lo ingrese el usuario.

Un ejemplo de cómo se usa es:

```
String number = "666444555"
PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
try {
  PhoneNumber number = phoneUtil.parse(number, "ES");
} catch (NumberParseException e) {
  System.err.println("NumberParseException was thrown: " + e.toString());
}
```

Ahora hay una serie de métodos pero el más importante sería:

```
boolean isValid = phoneUtil.isValidNumber(number); // retorna true
```

Si quieres ver el número en formato internacional:

```
System.out.println(phoneUtil.format(number, PhoneNumberFormat.INTERNATIONAL));
```

Para ver un demo y probar si cumple exactamente todos tus requerimientos, [puedes ir acá](http://libphonenumber.appspot.com/).

Comment: Excelente, siempre prefiero evitar re-inventar la rueda a menos que sea por temas didácticos